# How to delete value from redis using python?

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, scrapyd

When I connect to Redis as a client I get first value from specific key (ZRANGE type). Here is code how it works

```
class RedisPriorityQueue(Base):

    def pop(self, timeout=0):
        pipe = self.server.pipeline()
        pipe.multi()
        pipe.zrange(self.key, 0, 0).zremrangebyrank(self.key, 0, 0)
        results, count = pipe.execute()
        if results:
            return self._decode_item(results[0])
```

Then when trying to remove first value from this key but nothing happened.

But if I using redis-cli to remove first value it works.

I'm using python 2 and redis lib (2.10.5)

Update. This error happens only if this function called from scrapy scheduler. If write pure python script it works fine.

Comment: I edited my post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What specifically are the results from executing the pipe when it doesn't work? This sounds like a configuration error, where your setup when called from scrapy is somehow different.

Comment: 2 variants happened:
1) pipe goes through all values, but doesn't delete them.
2) pipe returns only first value and doesn't delete it.
I tried to put code in init where I delete all values in loop and it works.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. The `pipe.multi()` isn't necessary, but I don't see how that could harm anything.

Comment: I can provide full source code. Can this help?